# Python 3 arcgis.gis.user for lastLogin accessing ArcGIS Portal

Tags: python-3.x, arcgis, esri

This is being ran on Windows 10 64 bit machine, using Python 3, jupyter labs version 1.6.1.

I am working on a small script using Jupyter Notebook to access my local portal site. With the code snippet below, you can see that I am looking to acquire the portal groups and the users in each group.

The information I am working on obtaining is when each user was created (not as important) and last accessed. This seems to work just fine, the scrip prints out the users and the dates for which their accounts were created, but the same thing for the last accessed date is throwing an error.

I have reviewed [arcgis.gis module](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.gis.toc.html#user)
to read up on the parameters for the arcgis.gis.users class and LastLogin does exist. Another note I should include is that when I use an individual user, such as myself if I were the logged in user, the last access function works. It just seems like when I am passing the users being looped using the "user2" variable, the script doesn't like this.

I also checked the .get() for the acceptable parameters which is "username" and this seems fine.

```
import time
from arcgis.gis import GIS
portal = r"*" #this would be the portal or arcgis online url
username = "*" #using admin credentials here
password = "*"
gis = GIS(portal, username, password)
groups = gis.groups.search()

for group in groups:
    print(group)
    accounts = gis.users.search()
    for account in accounts:
        #user = gis.users.account
        #user = gis.users.search(query="username = {}".format(account.username))
        #print(account.email)
        user2 = gis.users.get(username="{}".format(account.username))
        print(account.username)
        created_time = time.localtime(user2.created/1000)
        print("Created: {}/{}/{}".format(created_time[0], created_time[1], created_time[2]))
        last_accessed = time.localtime(user2.lastLogin/1000)
        print("Last active: {}/{}/{}".format(last_accessed[0], last_accessed[1], last_accessed[2]))
```

The error is what I received when trying to pass the "user2" in line 23 for the last_accessed variable.

```
 OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-3-3a539a5c371d> in <module>
         21         created_time = time.localtime(user2.created/1000)
         22         print("Created: {}/{}/{}".format(created_time[0], created_time[1], created_time[2]))
    ---> 23         last_accessed = time.localtime(user2.lastLogin/1000)
         24         print("Last active: {}/{}/{}".format(last_accessed[0], last_accessed[1], 
    last_accessed[2]))
         25 

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Comment: Is it possible that it's failing for some users who may have never logged in? Or is this behavior consistent for every user?

Comment: Erica. The credentials I am using are the admin credentials. Which is what I need to use to set up the script to pull the information about when the users profiles were created and last accessed, etc. I can obtain the "Created" information with the same object pass into the: created_time = time.localtime(user2.created/1000), but the error barks when it reaches last access. I wouldn't think this would be the case for every user if the the logic in the created_time variable works. But I know for sure that each user has logged in at least once, the first profile is my user account. Thanks

Comment: The only thing wrong with that line would be that `user2.lastLogin` is null. I would just put a check before execution `if user2.lastLogin is not None:` to ensure that line is oly executed if a user has logged in

Comment: If I run the same code for: user2 = gis.users.get(username="{}".format(account.username)) and specify a specific user account, it will give me the last user login date, but the user names vary with a "@" in the name to point at a domain. Some are names like john.doe and they work but if one is like this: spatialcoder@stackoverflow it says invalid arguement. But I know the value it is being passed it not null, because I print the username before the date I want it to print. It seems like it isn't accepting special characters, but they are valid usernames

Comment: @R10t-- Sorry, I completely missed your point here and that was exactly the case.

Comment: @Erica That was exactly the case as well. It was the shear fact that I had not caught the output and the logic wasn't checking if it was a value other than none or 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further investigation, it seems as though the .lastLogin snippet works. The problem was in the ArcGIS portal environment, where there was a user that had not yet signed in with their credentials (typically using admin creds). The value passed into the code was passing a -1 and the conversion of that value wasn't accounted for in the base library, so we added an if statement to verify that the value needs to be > 0, if it isn't then we log that the user has not logged in yet.

Here is the updated code for the script.

accounts = gis.users.search()

for account in accounts:
user = gis.users.get("{}".format(account.username))

```
if account.username.startswith("esri"): # Disregard any generic named accounts such as those that do not seem user specific like esri_boundaries, etc... 
    pass
elif account.username.startswith("system_"): # Disregard any system related IDs such as "system_publisher" otherwise the parameter is not valid to pass for the last login.
    pass
else:
    print("Full Name: {}".format(user.fullName))
    print("Username: {}".format(user.username))
    created = time.localtime(user.created/1000)
    print("User created: {}/{}/{}".format(created[0], created[1], created[2]))
    if user.lastLogin > 0:
        last_accessed = time.localtime(user.lastLogin/1000)
        print("Last active: {}/{}/{}".format(last_accessed[0], last_accessed[1], last_accessed[2]))
    else:
        print("***{} Has not yet logged in".format(account.username))
    print()
```

print("Process Complete")